# compare one pixel with all pixels

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

i want to compare  pixel of an image with all pixel of second image and then next pixel  with all pixel of second image;
i am using this code in which i am comparing pixel (converted in byte) one pixel of one image with second pixel of second but i do not want this approach. Please reply fast.
Thanks in advance.

```
 public static double GetDifferentPercentageSneller(ref Bitmap bmp1, ref Bitmap bmp2)
    {

        //if (bmp1 == null || bmp2 == null)

        //    return 100.0;



        //if (bmp1.Size != bmp2.Size)

        //    return 100.0;



        //if (bmp1.PixelFormat != bmp2.PixelFormat)

        //    return 100.0;



        int iMismatch = 0;

        int iMatch = 0;



        unsafe
        {

            BitmapData data1 = bmp1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);

            BitmapData data2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);



            int pixelBytes = 0;



            switch (data1.PixelFormat)
            {

                case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:

                    pixelBytes = 4;

                    break;

                case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:

                    pixelBytes = 3;

                    break;

                default:

                    throw new Exception("Bitmap format not supported");

            }



            int paddingBytes = data1.Stride % pixelBytes;

            byte* location1 = (byte*)data1.Scan0;

            byte* location2 = (byte*)data2.Scan0;



            for (int y = 0; y < data1.Height; ++y)
            {

                for (int x = 0; x < data1.Width; ++x)
                {


                            if (*location1 == *location2)
                            {

                                iMatch++;


                            }
                            else
                            {

                                iMismatch++;

                            }
                    location1 += pixelBytes;

                    location2 += pixelBytes;

                }



                location1 += paddingBytes;

                location2 += paddingBytes;

            }



            bmp1.UnlockBits(data1);

            bmp2.UnlockBits(data2);

        }



        double percent = (double)iMatch/ (double)(iMismatch + iMatch);



        return percent * 100.0;

    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? state your problem may be i could find a better way to solve that

Comment: are you trying to compare two images' similarity?

Comment: actually i am doing this but it is not giving accurate results.. now i want to compare one pixel with all  pixels of other image..

Answer (score 2):

You have to always compare the LARGER image (both x, y) with the SMALLER. Although I don't know what your are exactly after, you can do it simply like this.

```
 BitmapImage Image1 = new BitmapImage(ImageStream);
 BitmapImage Image2 = new BitmapImage(ImageStream);
 int X = Image1.Width > Image2.Width ? Image2.Width : Image1.Width;
 int Y = Image1.Hieght > Image2.Height ? Image2.Heigth : Image1.Height;
 for(int x = 0; x < X; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < Y; y++){
       Color color1 = Image1.GetPixel(x, y);
       Color color2 = Image2.GetPixel(x, y);
       // Do comparison here
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Shahbaz If you wanna match both images, then calculate the hash of both images and compare them, but if you are after pattern matching, you can either use this or look for some ready to use libraries. However, at the lowest level you will have at least a nested loop, so I don't think there would be a faster approach. Please mention what exactly you wanna do so that I can maybe be able to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz: If you add breaks at the right time in this nested loop, it will surely become way faster, but please keep in mind that I do not have enough information about what exactly you are trying to achieve yet.

Comment: GetPixel is notoriously slow.  The same comparison should be able to be done using LockBits.